# How to re-use a function to output a returned value in multiple textfields?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to re-use a function that calculates the square of different numbers (inputted through different text-field) and displays them in different text-field. Here's my current HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    function square(a) {
      a = a * a;
      document.f.T2.value = a;
    }
  </script>
  <form name="f">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T1" onkeyup="square(document.f.T1.value)"></td>
        <td>Square</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T3" onkeyup="square(document.f.T3.value)"></td>
        <td>Square</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This works perfectly for the first integer, `a`. Couldn't figure how to make it work for `b` as well.

If I add this line of code within the function, it'll work for the first value as well.

```
document.f.T4.value=a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function square(value, target) {    
    target.value= value * value
}
```

and use it like:

```
<td>
   <input type="text" name="T1" onkeyup="square(this.value, document.f.T2)">
</td>
<td>Square</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" name="T2">
</td>
```

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jo960acq/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the current `input` element and the `target` to your function `square`.

## Suggestion

*Separate the responsibilities.* :-)

The following code snippet has a function for `square calculation` and another to get the values from the `input elements` and call the function `square`.

This way you can reuse your code!

```js
function square(a) {
  return a * a;
}

function squareFromElement(_this, target) {
  var a = square(_this.value);  
  document.getElementsByName(target)[0].value = a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="f">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T1" onkeyup="squareFromElement(this, 'T2')"></td>
        <td>Square</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T3" onkeyup="squareFromElement(this, 'T4')" )></td>
        <td>Square</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

See? now is setting the result into the right inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your function in another parameter the textbox that you want to show the results in. Also you can refer to the current textbox using `this` instead of fully qualifying it. Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    function square(a, result) {
      a = a * a;
      result.value = a;
    }
  </script>
  <form name="f">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T1" onkeyup="square(this.value, document.f.T2)"></td>
        <td>Square</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T3" onkeyup="square(this.value, document.f.T4)"></td>
        <td>Square</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="T4"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```